# Skype bot error on sending attachments/JSON

Tags: bots, botframework, skype

I was trying to send a JSON stringified object or an attachment through the session using `session.send`, I got the following error in the console and do not get any response from the bot.

> Error: Request to 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/SOMEHASHCODE/activities' failed: [400] Bad Request

When I checked the Skype channel issues in Microsoft Bot Framework, I see the following message for JSON objects

> Invalid XML in message text

and the following message for attachments.

> Unknown attachment type

The bot is working perfectly in Slack and Emulator. So it must not be the issue with the code.

```
// JSON object
session.send(JSON.stringify(session.conversationData.inputData, null, 2));

// Attachment message
session.send(new builder.Message(session)
    .text(`Here's the document:`)
    .addAttachment({
      contentUrl: `http://host:port/${filePath}`,
      contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
      name: 'Document.docx',
    }));
```

The JSON object which was sent was `{"name": "Philip John", "id": "444411111111",   "phone": "54545454", "email": "philip@john.com", "address": "Street 11 - 111, City , ", "job": "Software Tester", "date": "1st June 2017", "salary": "9000", "bankAccount": "DE121231231231231231" }`

Any idea how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Can you share the JSON object that caused the error?

Comment: @NilsW please check. Added the JSON object.

Comment: for question #2 - Word file attachment, can you link to an example file that produces the error?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question #1: Sending stringified JSON in Bot Framework message.

When you stringify JSON with the following settings:

```
JSON.stringify(inputJson, null, 2)
```

It produces output with new-line symbols, which is designed to "pretty print" console output in a terminal or browser console, but does not produce the same formatting when sending as a message via Bot Framework SDK.

```
// string output of JSON.stringify(inputJson, null, 2)
var stringified = = '{\n  "name": "Philip John",\n  "id": "444411111111",\n  "phone": "54545454",\n  "email": "philip@john.com",\n  "address": "Street 11 - 111, City , ",\n  "job": "Software Tester",\n  "date": "1st June 2017",\n  "salary": "9000",\n  "bankAccount": "DE121231231231231231"\n}';
```

To get proper line breaks in your bot message, you need to use two `\n` characters instead of one. For example:

```
// bot formatted message string with line breaks
var botJsonMessage = '{\n\n  "name": "Philip John",\n\n  "id": "444411111111",\n\n  "phone": "54545454",\n\n  "email": "philip@john.com",\n\n  "address": "Street 11 - 111, City , ",\n\n  "job": "Software Tester",\n\n  "date": "1st June 2017",\n\n  "salary": "9000",\n\n  "bankAccount": "DE121231231231231231"\n\n}';
```

---

Answer to question #2: Supported message attachment types in Bot Framework.

Currently, `contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'` is an unsupported content type. Use `application/word` instead.